# How can I stop myself from committing to the master branch in git?

Tags: git, version-control, ubuntu-11.04

My ideal workflow would be to commit changes onto `dev` and only merge changes to master via `git merge --no-ff dev`, but occassionaly what happens is:

*On dev*

```
dev: git add .
dev: git commit -m "Cured cancer."
dev: git checkout master
master: git merge --no-ff dev
```

*Writes some more code*

```
master: git commit -a -m "Did something amazing"
```

Whops, just committed to master. If I'm lucky I realize it right away, but if I don't I can push the branch upstream with another 10 changes on top. So this ends up in remote:

```
Master   -------- Merge --- commit - commit --------------- Merge
Dev      \ Commit/                        \ commit - commit /
```

While it should look like this:

```
Master   -------- Merge ------------- Merge --------------------- Merge
Dev      \ Commit/     \ commit commit /  \ commit - commit - commit /
```

How can I remove the human factor (i.e. my stupidity) and stop myself from committing to the master branch? I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can I ask why it matters? Nobody sees which local branch you committed to so if you push to master in the end any way, does it really matter where you made the original commit locally?

Comment: @CharlesBailey: A key benefit of using git is the ability to create a meaningful history, which provides more control over how code is shared and integrated. If a commit accidentally ends up in master with 10 changes after it, it becomes awkward to separate it out if the feature isn't ready for a release while the other 10 changes are.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: I don't disagree with what you've said, but I don't see how which branch the original commit was made on makes affects the difficulty of the "undo" operation.

Comment: @Charles Bailey - It's just how our development flow is setup. You commit to your own dev branch and merge them into master. It also ads a bit of noise when there's a bunch of tiny commits on master. The difficulty of the undo operation is if someone pulls master after I've pushed and so if I try to undo they can have pulled the master, which would cause a conflict. I don't in actual practice care that much, it would just be nice if the commit history was consistent.

Comment: @Charles Bailey - Oh and they do see which commit went where. My local master tracks remote master, my local dev tracks remote dev.

Comment: OK, it sounds like there's a missing step in your description then. Is the central dev always a descendant of the central master?

Comment: @CharlesBailey - Oh sorry for not being clear then. Yes my `dev` descends from `master`, it's actually called `kit_dev` and each person has their own `<peson>_dev` branch. We also have branches for major features like `dev_site_redesign` (descending from master) with `dev_site_redesign_kit` if more than one person works on it.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a bullet-proof solution, but you could install git-completion.bash and use its PS1 enhancement to display the current branch (and other useful stuff) as part of your command prompt. See [here](http://blog.bitfluent.com/post/27983389/git-utilities-you-cant-live-without) for an explanation.

It won't stop you from committing to master, but it will make it difficult to forget which branch you're on.

Answer (score 3):

You could pretty easily write a [pre-commit hook](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) to check your current branch and reject the commit based on the branch name.

Comment: +1, but don't forget to allow appropriate commits to master — i.e., merge from dev. Not sure how easy/difficult that is.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to setup something similar where only hudson commits as it will merge the remote branch you commit into master and then push those into our git Soooooo our mainline master is only GOOD code and no developer can be affected by another one breaking the build...oh happy day.

pre-receive script(server side - don't put locally) ....

```
#!/bin/sh
# <oldrev> <newrev> <refname>
# update a blame tree
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    echo "STARTING [$oldrev $newrev $ref]"

if [ $ref == "refs/heads/master" ] && [ $USER != "hudson" ]
then
    echo "YOU CANNOT COMMIT STUFF TO MASTER BRANCH"
    echo "TO CORRECT THIS run"
    echo "git branch -c <branch name> then run"
    echo "git push <reponame> <branch name>"
    echo "and hudson will take and push to master IF it passes the tests"
    exit 1;
else
    echo "This is hudson, allowing commit to master"
fi

done
```

and then of course, I HATE polling so on post-receive I do something like this(NOTE that the hudson user cannot run the curl command or you end up in infinite loop as it keeps pushing changes it makes to master branch)...

post-receive script(server side-don't put locally)

```
echo "User=$USER"

if [ "hudson" != $USER ]
then
    echo "Notifying hudson to build NOW"
    curl http://10.222.0.168:8080/job/stserver1/build?delay=0sec
    echo "Done notifying"
else
    echo "This is hudson, not triggering build now"
fi
```

NOTE: I haven't figured out the way for a developer to revert their commit to master yet though :(.  still working on that one.

Comment: Dean, I've removed a link to your blog from three of your most recent posts. Signatures are not appropriate on Stack Overflow, and signatures that serve only to advertise your blog are doubly so. If you link to an article of yours that goes into more detail on one of your answers, that'd be more appropriate. See [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed) for more detail.